# Condição de saída no do-while em código C

Tags: c, condição, switch, do-while

Preciso que o usuário insira os números 1, 2 ou 3 para escolher as localidades, e se não selecionar uma delas, perguntar de novo.

Porém ao inserir o número 0 ou 4, por exemplo, ele volta na tela inicial (que seria o menu, de destinos, custos e sair).

Preciso que ele diga "Informe um codigo de cidade valido" e questione de novo um dos três números.

O que fiz de errado?

```
printf("Selecione a opcao desejada:\n 1 - Destinos \n 2 - Custos \n 3 - Sair\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    switch(op) {
        case 1 : printf("\n1 - Destinos:\n\n Codigo da cidade      Valor da passagem por pessoa\n\n");
                 printf(" 1 - Nova York    ===>      R$3.231,00\n");
                 printf(" 2 - Londres      ===>      R$3.789,00\n");
                 printf(" 3 - Dubai        ===>      R$4.932,00\n\n");
                 printf("Informe o numero de seu destino\n");
                 scanf("%d", &destino);
                 if (destino <= 0 && destino > 3) {
                 do{
                 printf("Informe um codigo de cidade valido.\n");
                 scanf("%d", &destino);
                 } while (destino <= 0 && destino > 3);
                 }
```

Comment: É impossível um valor ser <= 0 e simultaneamente > 3. Reveja a definição dos operadores lógicos && e ||.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Isso?

```
printf("Selecione a opcao desejada:\n 1 - Destinos \n 2 - Custos \n 3 - Sair\n");
scanf("%d", &op);
switch(op) {
case 1:
    printf("\n1 - Destinos:\n\n Codigo da cidade      Valor da passagem por pessoa\n\n");
    printf(" 1 - Nova York    ===>      R$3.231,00\n");
    printf(" 2 - Londres      ===>      R$3.789,00\n");
    printf(" 3 - Dubai        ===>      R$4.932,00\n\n");
    printf("Informe o numero de seu destino\n");
    scanf("%d", &destino);
    while (destino < 1 || destino > 3) {
         printf("Informe um codigo de cidade valido.\n");
         scanf("%d", &destino);
    }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ValidationExit.c).

Comment: Só explicitando, a ideia principal foi a troca do operador lógico `&&` pelo operador `||` (já que o usuário deve entrar com os dados novamente se o `destino` escolhido for menor que 1 **ou** maior que 3).

Comment: Eu não expliquei porque sequer sei se é o que a pergunta pede. Se eu tiver certeza, aí eu posso complementar.